# How to setup a server for my application for cloud computing?

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack

Requirement:
I am the developer of a software which can do enormous number crunching.
The number crunching software should be installed on the server.
I have a client side application which communicates with the server side application.

Problem:
I went though the Ubuntu website and got confused.
I understand that I should install Ubuntu server on my PC.
However I did not understand what is MAAS, OpenStack and JUJU?
Do I have to install these as well?
I am trying networking and setting up server for the first time, hence please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Doesn't look like you need to go into "cloud computing" at all. Install the server, then you application, configure everything, ...and that's about it.

Comment: I had the same feeling. But then what is cloud computing meant for?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Juju to create a Juju Charm for your server side application then you can deploy your solution to any major cloud via a single command. For more information look at https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started.